# How to list the code of a verb in J

Tags: j

In the console, typing a single verb without parameters will print its content:

```
   tolower

3 : 0
x=. I. 26 > n=. ((65+i.26){a.) i. t=. ,y
($y) $ ((x{n) { (97+i.26){a.) x}t
)
```

That's nice for development, but unexploitable during execution. Is there a way to do that dynamically? Is there a verb that can return the contents of another verb?

For example:

```
showverb 'tolower'
```

or

```
showverb tolower
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use its [representation](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx005.htm). For example the boxed representation (`5!:2`) of `tolower` is:

```
   (5!:2) <'tolower'
┌─┬─┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
│3│:│x=. I. 26 > n=. ((65+i.26){a.) i. t=. ,y│
│ │ │($y) $ ((x{n) { (97+i.26){a.) x}t       │
└─┴─┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

its linear (`5!:5`) is:

```
   (5!:5) <'tolower'
3 : 0
x=. I. 26 > n=. ((65+i.26){a.) i. t=. ,y
($y) $ ((x{n) { (97+i.26){a.) x}t
)
```