# How can I extract a verb definition as data?

Tags: j

I would like to extract an explicit definition as a string which, if fed back to 
3:0 or 4:0, would create the same verb. I feel sure I have seen something that does this, but I can't find it.

As a poor substitute, is there a way to turn off the . . . display for long output so I could just enter the verb name and cut and paste the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/12181127/349708? Or maybe you mean something different?

Comment: Yes, my question was a duplicate. Thank you for pointing out the answer.